Indexing numpy array of shape `(A, B, C)` with `[[a, b], [c, d], :]` (`0 <= a, b < A`, `0 <= c, d < B`) produces shape `(2, C)` instead of `(2, 2, C)`
Here's the example:
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(100)
B = np.random.randint(100)
C = np.random.randint(100)
print(f"{A=}, {B=}, {C=}")

x = np.random.random((A, B, C))
print(f"{x.shape=}")

a = np.random.randint(0, A)
b = np.random.randint(0, A)
print(f"{a=}, {b=}")

c = np.random.randint(0, B)
d = np.random.randint(0, B)
print(f"{c=}, {d=}")

print(f"{x[[a, b], [c, d], :].shape=}")
print(f"{x[[a, b]][:, [c, d]].shape=}")

A=7, B=40, C=57
x.shape=(7, 40, 57)
a=4, b=1
c=10, d=5
x[[a, b], [c, d], :].shape=(2, 57)
x[[a, b]][:, [c, d]].shape=(2, 2, 57)

I would have expected indexing with [[a, b], [c, d], :] to produce a shape (2, 2, C)?

If you want a reproducible example you should set the seed: np.random.seed(0)

[[a, b], [c, d]] on a 2d array selects a 'diagonal', 2 items, not a block.  That is [a,c] and [b,d].  [[[a],[b]], [c,d]] is required to get the 'block'

Use np.ix_ to get an open mesh.  Unfortunately it doesn't play particularly nice with :, but you can get around it:
print(f"{x[np.ix_([a, b], [c, d], range(C))].shape = }")
x[np.ix_([a, b], [c, d], range(C))].shape = (2, 2, 77)

print(f"{x[np.ix_([a, b], range(B), [c, d])].shape = }")
x[np.ix_([a, b], range(B), [c, d])].shape = (2, 92, 2)


As an aside, I had never seen that functionality of the print function, very cool to learn something today!

If you are referring to f"{x=}", that's a functionality of f-strings, not print ;-)

@DanielF Thank you so much. I am having a ton of trouble deciphering the numpy docs (whether around "Advanced Indexing" or np.ix_). Was going to raise those issues in the comments, but I think it would be better to create separate questions for those (would also force me to be more precise, which tends to end up answering my "questions"). Again, thank you!
